# Json.Net deserialize of "m³/h" is coming as "m�/h"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.dll (Json.NET) V4.5.0.0 in .NET 3.5 SP1.
I have a Json file containing "m³/h", when I deserialize this into an object I am getting  "m�/h".

Here is the code to deserialize the file to object

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("myData.json");
var myObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myObj>>(jsonString);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is encoding of file?

Comment: File was encoded in ANSI. I am able to solve by string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("myData.json", new UTF7Encoding());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that the json-file has an different file encoding. Use the second parameter of ReadAllText to define the correct encoding.

Comment: Thanks for showing the right direction and help, UTF7Encoding solved my issue. string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("myData.json", new UTF7Encoding());